# How can I parse the below texts from web service?

Tags: php

I have the below response from the AWS webservice and want to parse it ? How can I do this. Please help me.

```
    b336825b-63244675-4e7e-WJ5OPBUYS3KGPMZB7EQ61-06-05T11:18:19Z2011-05-06T11:15:49Z2011-05-06T11:18:19Z2011-05-06T11:21:34Z<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuestionFormAnswers xmlns="test">
<Answer>
<QuestionIdentifier>testDetlocat</QuestionIdentifier>
<FreeText>Location 1&#13;
Location 2 of the location 1</FreeText>
</Answer>
<Answer>
<QuestionIdentifier>testerName</QuestionIdentifier>
<FreeText>test DM</FreeText>
</Answer>
<Answer>
<QuestionIdentifier>testTranslang</QuestionIdentifier>
<FreeText>English</FreeText>
</Answer>
<Answer>
<QuestionIdentifier>testNotes</QuestionIdentifier>
<FreeText>Location is US, HIT approval rate (%) is not less than 100 </FreeText>
</Answer>
<Answer>
<QuestionIdentifier>Submit</QuestionIdentifier>
<FreeText>Submit</FreeText>
</Answer>
<Answer>
<QuestionIdentifier>testTimestamp</QuestionIdentifier>
<FreeText>4;47</FreeText>
</Answer>
<Answer>
<QuestionIdentifier>testCountry</QuestionIdentifier>
<FreeText>india</FreeText>
</Answer>
<Answer>
<QuestionIdentifier>testUrgent</QuestionIdentifier>
<FreeText>1</FreeText>
</Answer>
<Answer>
<QuestionIdentifier>testLanguage</QuestionIdentifier>
<FreeText>English</FreeText>
</Answer>
<Answer>
<QuestionIdentifier>testTranslation</QuestionIdentifier>
<FreeText>In tamil and english</FreeText>
</Answer>
<Answer>
<QuestionIdentifier>testHITname</QuestionIdentifier>
<FreeText>@test</FreeText>
</Answer>
<Answer>
<QuestionIdentifier>testUsername </QuestionIdentifier>
<FreeText>sdftest</FreeText>
</Answer>
</QuestionFormAnswers>
```

This string to be striped before parsing **b336825b-63244675-4e7e-WJ5OPBUYS3KGPMZB7EQ61 ...

Comment: use simple simplexml_string() to parse it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string utf8_decode ( string $data )` function for parsing this string.

```
                           OR
```

you can get more help from [This link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)

Try this may useful to you..

Thanks